# поиск и замена обєкта в двухмерном массиве javascript (без мутации)

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

```
[
  [
    {
      "currentDay": "2019-09-29T21:00:00.000Z",
      "firstRowBorder": true,
      "blank": true
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": true,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-09-30T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "1",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": true,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-01T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "2",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": true,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-02T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "3",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": true,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-03T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "4",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": true,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-04T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "5",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": true,
      "dayLastRow": true,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-05T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "6",
      "blank": false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-06T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "7",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-07T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "8",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-08T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "9",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-09T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "10",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-10T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "11",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-11T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "12",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": true,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-12T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "13",
      "blank": false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-13T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "14",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-14T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "15",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-15T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "16",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-16T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "17",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-17T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "18",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-18T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "19",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": true,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-19T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "20",
      "blank": false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-20T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "21",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-21T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "22",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": true,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-22T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "23",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-23T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "24",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-24T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "25",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-25T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "26",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": true,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-26T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "27",
      "blank": false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-27T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "28",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-28T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "29",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-29T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "30",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "dayFirstRow": false,
      "dayLastRow": true,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-10-30T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "31",
      "blank": false
    },
    {
      "currentDay": "2019-10-31T21:00:00.000Z",
      "firstRowBorder": false,
      "blank": true
    },
    {
      "currentDay": "2019-11-01T21:00:00.000Z",
      "firstRowBorder": false,
      "blank": true
    },
    {
      "currentDay": "2019-11-02T21:00:00.000Z",
      "firstRowBorder": false,
      "blank": true
    }
  ]
]
```

это массив календаря, при клике на ячейке календаря например кликаю на

```
{
      "dayFirstRow": true,
      "dayLastRow": false,
      "selected": false,
      "currentDay": "2019-09-30T21:00:00.000Z",
      "text": "1",
      "blank": false
    }
```

у меня есть selectedDate что я по нему кликнул и ему нужно установить "selected": true и заменить в изначальном масиве

```
monthRows = monthRows.map(week => (
        week.map(day => {
          if (day.currentDay === selectedDate) {
            return {
              ...day,
              selected: true
            }
          }
          else return day
        })
      ));
```

в итоге получиться то что нужно, но с мутацией, вопрос в том как это сделать без мутации monthRows = [...monthRows, ????]?

Comment: через forEach сделайте

Comment: Вообще-то в приведённом коде мутации нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
monthRows = monthRows.map(week => {
  var i = week.findIndex(day => day.currentDay === selectedDate)

  return i === -1
    ? week
    : [...week.slice(0, i), { ...week[i], selected: true }, ...week.slice(i+1)];
})
```